# Spellchecker in LyX: Right dictionary configuration

Tags: 11.10, latex, dictionary, lyx

I have installed LyX 2.0.0 from the Ubuntu 11.10 software center. I am trying to use the spellchecker but it is not working as it is not able to identify any grammatical mistake.

Which would be the right configuration to link LyX with a given dictionary (for several languages as well) such as the pre-installed Aspell in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, LyX has a spellchecker, but no grammar checker.

Comment: LyX definitely has no grammar checker. See http://wiki.lyx.org/Tools/LyX-GrammarChecker